# Java Access to the Webcam when another program use the webcam

Tags: java, maven, webcam, webcam-capture, openimaj

I need to create a program who can use webcam in same time of another program.
So i use [Sarxos Webcam-capture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture).

I try to play with the lock like this :

```
webcam.getLock().unlock();
```

Or

```
webcam.getLock().disable();
```

But my program or the other program lost the webcam or simply crash.

StackTrace of crash :

com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot execute task
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:72)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor.process(WebcamProcessor.java:140)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamTask.process(WebcamTask.java:46)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask.open(WebcamOpenTask.java:20)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.open(Webcam.java:271)
    at webcam.webcam.MyRunnable.run(DetectMotion.java:70)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamException: Cannot start native grabber!
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.buildin.WebcamDefaultDevice.open(WebcamDefaultDevice.java:330)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.cgt.WebcamOpenTask.handle(WebcamOpenTask.java:38)
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamProcessor$AtomicProcessor.run(WebcamProcessor.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Do you get any error (or stacktrace) at the crash? Please add it to your post.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot this important thing

Comment: I can't know if webcam is currenly by another program write in C / C++ or stuff like that. That is the problem